# R no longer runs in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, blas, domc

I run (k)Ubuntu 12.04.2 and R 3.0.1

I wrote a bunch of code that used to run in parallel, but now it no longer does. Not even this runs in parallel any more:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(4)
Results = foreach (i = 1:1e6, .combine = "c") %dopar% {
  sqrt(i)
}
```

And that definitely should. What I think broke it is either the R 3.0.1 update or a `-dev, -devel` BLAS package I installed. (openBLAS I think)

I've tried `system(sprintf("taskset -p 0xffffffff %d", Sys.getpid()))` as suggested elsewhere, and get this result:

```
pid 2415's current affinity mask: 1
pid 2415's new affinity mask: f
```

I've also tried running R with:

```
taskset 0xffff R
```

However after either of these steps running the loop still only uses one core.

I want parallel processing back! How can I get it?

Comment: Have you tried executing R via taskset, as in `$ taskset 0xffff R`?  The CPU affinity may need to be set correctly before OpenBLAS is initialized.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that. Edited the Q to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! Ironically, to get parallel processing back I had to do both of the steps I mentioned in the Q **at the same time**

So, start R with

```
taskset 0xffff R
```

Then run

```
system(sprintf("taskset -p 0xffffffff %d", Sys.getpid()))
```

Within R.

Voila, parallel processing returns

Comment: That's bizarre.  Did you get the same messages about the affinity mask when you executed "taskset -p" this time, or were they different?

Comment: I got 1, then f. It's confusing the hell out of me.

Comment: It's possible that it has something to do with the various shell script wrappers around R.  Could you try using `Rscript`, using a command like `$ taskset 0xffff Rscript domc.R` without executing `taskset -p` within the R script?  I think Rscript is still a simple executable, so there may be a difference.